# rearrange list elements in lisp

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

I have this project in my AI course to make a few functions in lisp and I just can't get why one of my functions isn't working properly. The function is supposed to take a list as argument and return a list where the arguments from the given list which show up more then once are grouped together, something like this:
(2, 4, 6, 5, 4, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 75, 87) -> ( 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 5, 7,3,  75, 87).
I first made two functions, one which deletes the given argument from the given list ( brisi ( x, l) ) and the other which counts how many times does element x shows up in list l ( brojPonavljanja (x, l) )

```
(defun brisi (x l)
  (setq duz (length l))
  (setq i 0)
  (setq br 0)
  (loop
    (when (= i duz)
      (return)
    )
    (when (= x (nth i l))
      (incf br)
    )
    (incf i)
  )
  (setq duz1 (- duz br))
  (setq l1 (make-list duz1))
  (setq j 0)
  (setq i 0)
  (loop
    (if (/= x (nth i l))
      (progn
        (setf (nth j l1) (nth i l))
        (incf i)
        (incf j)
      )
      (incf i)
    )
    (when (= i duz)
      (return l1)
    )
  )
)
( defun brojPojava (x l)
  (if ( null l)
    0
    ( if (= (car l) x)
        (+ 1 (brojPojava x (cdr l)))
        (brojPojava x (cdr l))
    )
  )
)
(defun skupi(l)
  (setq duz (length l))
  (setq l1 (make-list duz))
  (setq i 0)
  (setq pos 0)
  (loop
    (when (= i (length l))
      (return l1)
    )
    (setf elem (nth i l))
    (setf br (brojPojava elem l))
    (when (> br 1)
      (setf l (brisi elem l))
      (setq j 0)
      (loop
        (when (= br j)
          (return)
        )
        (setf (nth pos l1) elem) ; <-- ######
        (incf j)
        (incf pos)
      )
      (setq i -1)
    )
    (incf i)
  )
)
```

So the last function skupi(l) creates problems. I did notice a strange occurrence, at one point I use my brisi function to delete the element which repeats in the list and I copy it to a new list, but the list from which I deleted the repeating elements (list l) suddenly changes after one line of code (I put an arrow and couple of # on that line). I don't know why is this happening.

Comment: Why are you using global variables *everywhere*?

Comment: aren't these supposed to be local, and globals require special declaration ?

Comment: Local to what? Lisp doesn't have blocks.

Comment: local to the functions in which they're used, though I have just started working in lisp so it is all new to me

Comment: You should use `LET` to bind local variables within a function.

Comment: Oh I see, could this error be caused because of this ?

Comment: Common Lisp has built-in `REMOVE` and `COUNT` functions.

Comment: You can get all the similar elements grouped together simply by sorting the list.

Comment: Part of the project was to make all of these by ourselves

Comment: well, sort would work if numbers only were the members of the list, but this isn't necessarily the case

Comment: `setq` *alters* an already existing variable. The variable can be defined as arguments, `let` variables or globally defined with `defparameter`, `defvar` or `declare`. Since we see `duz` is not defined we can assume they are global variables with bad names (no `*earmuffs*`)

Comment: @waltdisney By using `=` everywhere, your code *assumes* that only numbers will be found in the list (and `sort` accepts arbitrary comparison functions in the first place).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your style doesn't resemble functional very much. You could write it, for example, in the following (not the most efficient, but more concise) way:

```
(defun group-list (lst)
  (when lst
    (nconc (make-list (count (car lst) lst) :initial-element (car lst))
      (group-list (remove (car lst) lst)))))
```

though I'm providing the solution for the sake of learning, rather then for copy-pasting.

Comment: thanks, this does exactly what I described. I am not very comfortable with recursions so I avoided it, but this really is way more conciser then my idea

Comment: @waltdisney If you're going to use this solution, I'd suggest trying to optimize it (for the sake of learning), as currently it traverses the list twice per step, but could do it only once.

Comment: oh I see, okay then I'll try to make it as optimal as possible

Answer (score 0):

You could do it iteratively with two passes through the list and the help of some lookup tables (and some helper functions):

```
(defun gen-elements (element count)
  (loop repeat count
     collect element))

(defun group-list (list)
  (let ((done (make-hash-table))
        (counts (make-hash-table)))
    (loop for element in list
          do (incf (gethash element counts 0)))
    (loop for element in list
          if (not (gethash element done))
          append (progn
                    (setf (gethash element done) t)
                    (gen-elements element (gethash element counts))))))
```